# C# Generics - How to use type

Tags: c#, generics

I am fairly new to C# generics and am wondering how a few things work.

If I have this:

```
public class Foo<T>
```

On my class I have a method GetType, which will simply return the type of T. How would I do that so my method would de able to work with T.

```
public string GetType();
{
    return T.GetType().ToString();
}
```

I'm trying to learn a simple example to help me understand.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to override `public Type GetType()` (Type instead of string)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public string GetTypeName()
{
    return typeof(T).ToString();
}
```

`T` is not an instance of something, it is actual *type parameter*. Similarly you can't say `String.GetType()`, but you can say `typeof(String)`. In general, you call `GetType()` on instances and `typeof(something)` on types.

Also I've renamed your `GetType` method into `GetTypeName` because method `GetType` is declared on `object` type and thus compiler would complain if you try to use it.

And yet one thing: semicolon is illegal before method body, so I removed it.